# String between pipes

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file which contains music chords between pipes. I literally just want to extract the chords from the file. Any suggestion on regular expression which will work.

Example:

```
title: You've got a Friend
artist: Roberta Flack and Donny Hathaway
metre: 4/4
tonic: Ab

0.000000000 silence
0.255419501 A, intro, | Ab:maj | Db:maj/5 | Ab:maj | G:hdim7 C:7 |, (synth)
14.013514739
```

My desired output:

```
Ab:maj, Db:maj/5 , Ab:maj, G:hdim7 C:7
```

Comment: Any attempt to share with us?

Comment: If that is the only place pipes appear in your data, you don't need regex.  I would just use split('|') on your text, slice the list to drop the first and last entry, then join them with a comma separator to get your output.  It's a one-liner for you to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.split()` function in the following way:

```
yourChords = "0.000000000 silence 0.255419501 A, intro, | Ab:maj | Db:maj/5 | Ab:maj | G:hdim7 C:7 |, (synth) 14.013514739"

print yourChords.split("|")
```

This would output:

```
['0.000000000 silence 0.255419501 A, intro, ', ' Ab:maj ', ' Db:maj/5 ', ' Ab:maj ', ' G:hdim7 C:7 ', ', (synth) 14.013514739']
```

There you have an array containing your chords.